# How do drug companies know how to produce a generic drug?

Tags: medications

Do the original companies have to reveal their manufacturing process to the public before they sell the drugs and the other companies can copy from them after their patent is expired?

Comment: I think the contents are in the patent.

Comment: When you patent, you have to tell the world how to replicate your invention.

Comment: So why do they patent it? Are they afraid the information will leak?

Comment: So they have patent protection for X years.  If they don't patent someone could come up with it independently.

Comment: I think it's better for them to take the risk someone will come to it independently than reveal their formula and let anyone produce it after the patent is expired.